# csv writer output in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have parsed some *txt* files and obtain the following list:

```
price = ['S-1', '20040319', '\t\t\t\tDIGIRAD CORP', '\t\t0000707388', 'price to be between $and $per ', 'S-1', '20040408', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761', 'S-1', '20041027', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761', 'S-1', '20050630', '\t\t\t\tSEALY CORP', '\t\t0000748015', 'S-1', '20140512', '\t\t\t\tCITIZENS FINANCIAL GROUP INC/RI', '\t\t0000759944', 'initial public offering and no public market exists for our shares. We anticipate that the initial public offering price will be between $and', 'S-1', '20110523', '\t\t\t\tCeres, Inc.', '\t\t0000767884', '    aggregate capital expenditures will be between $0.3&#160;million', 'S-1', '20171023', '\t\t\t\tBLUEGREEN VACATIONS CORP', '\t\t0000778946', '        <div style="margin-top:14pt; text-align:justify; line-height:12pt;">This is the initial public offering of Bluegreen Vacations Corporation. We are offering &#8194;&#8194; shares of our common stock and the selling shareholder identified in this prospectus is offering &#8194;&#8194; shares of our common stock. We will not receive any of the proceeds from the sale of shares by the selling shareholder. We anticipate that the initial public offering price of our common stock will be between $&#8199;&#8199; and $&#8199;&#8199; per ', 'S-1', '20020813', '\t\t\t\tVISTACARE INC', '\t\t0000787030']
```

My desired output is a *csv* file where each row starts with each "`S-1`" document (corresponding to a different company). So I wrote a second list that creates sublists of the above starting in every `’S-1’` :

```
price2 = [s.strip('|').split('|') for s in re.split(r'(?=S-1)', '|'.join(price)) if s]
print(price2)
[['S-1', '20040319', '\t\t\t\tDIGIRAD CORP', '\t\t0000707388', 'price to be between $and $per '], ['S-1', '20040408', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761'], ['S-1', '20041027', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761'], ['S-1', '20050630', '\t\t\t\tSEALY CORP', '\t\t0000748015'], ['S-1', '20140512', '\t\t\t\tCITIZENS FINANCIAL GROUP INC/RI', '\t\t0000759944', 'initial public offering and no public market exists for our shares. We anticipate that the initial public offering price will be between $and'], ['S-1', '20110523', '\t\t\t\tCeres, Inc.', '\t\t0000767884', '    aggregate capital expenditures will be between $0.3&#160;million'], ['S-1', '20171023', '\t\t\t\tBLUEGREEN VACATIONS CORP', '\t\t0000778946', '        <div style="margin-top:14pt; text-align:justify; line-height:12pt;">This is the initial public offering of Bluegreen Vacations Corporation. We are offering &#8194;&#8194; shares of our common stock and the selling shareholder identified in this prospectus is offering &#8194;&#8194; shares of our common stock. We will not receive any of the proceeds from the sale of shares by the selling shareholder. We anticipate that the initial public offering price of our common stock will be between $&#8199;&#8199; and $&#8199;&#8199; per '], ['S-1', '20020813', '\t\t\t\tVISTACARE INC', '\t\t0000787030']]
```

To which I then write on a *csv* file:

```
with open('pricerange.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    wr = csv.writer(out_file)
    wr.writerow(["file_form", "filedate", "coname", "cik", "price_range"])  # Headlines in  top row
    wr.writerows(price2)
```

The output looks fine, with each sublist being placed in a new row (i.e. each row starts with the `’S-1’` element).
[image]

To clean even further the list, I still want to remove the special characters (e.g. `'&#8194'`). So I create a new `price3` list:

```
price3 = re.sub('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});', '', str(price2)) #remove special characters or html tags in original .txt files
print(price3)
[['S-1', '20040319', '\t\t\t\tDIGIRAD CORP', '\t\t0000707388', 'price to be between $and $per '], ['S-1', '20040408', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761'], ['S-1', '20041027', '\t\t\t\tBUCYRUS INTERNATIONAL INC', '\t\t0000740761'], ['S-1', '20050630', '\t\t\t\tSEALY CORP', '\t\t0000748015'], ['S-1', '20140512', '\t\t\t\tCITIZENS FINANCIAL GROUP INC/RI', '\t\t0000759944', 'initial public offering and no public market exists for our shares. We anticipate that the initial public offering price will be between $and'], ['S-1', '20110523', '\t\t\t\tCeres, Inc.', '\t\t0000767884', '    aggregate capital expenditures will be between $0.3million'], ['S-1', '20171023', '\t\t\t\tBLUEGREEN VACATIONS CORP', '\t\t0000778946', '        This is the initial public offering of Bluegreen Vacations Corporation. We are offering  shares of our common stock and the selling shareholder identified in this prospectus is offering  shares of our common stock. We will not receive any of the proceeds from the sale of shares by the selling shareholder. We anticipate that the initial public offering price of our common stock will be between $ and $ per '], ['S-1', '20020813', '\t\t\t\tVISTACARE INC', '\t\t0000787030']]
```

My surprise is that when I apply the code to transfer `price3` into a *csv* file, all elements are kept within the first column. See output:

[image]

Any suggestions? I can't see where's the bug...
Thank you so much

Comment: when you open `csv` in `Excel` probably it should ask for settings and you can choose `,` as separtor to read it correctly. At least I can do this when I open `csv` with `LibreOffice`.

Comment: Thank you @furas but this can not be the reason, because then the initial output (price2) would also suffer from the same problem, and it doesn't....

Comment: on your screen I see that `price2` has also problem with `,`  - you have all headers and values in single cell (in first column). so as for me `price2` also suffer for problem with `,` . OR maybe you are talking about different problem.

Comment: Thanks @furas, `price2` has this `,` issue as well, but I'm fine with that. The problem is `price3` writing every letter/symbol in a different row.

Comment: I run you code and your problem is that you convert list `price2` to string to use re - `str(price2)` - and later you write this string to file. `writerows()` needs list of lists but it get list of strings so it treat string as list of chars to get list of lists. You shouldn't convert list to string but use `re` with every element on list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug, the problem is that the `type(price)` is list and the `type(price3)` is string. When trying to write to file, the string is interpreted as a list of characters, so the code writes one character per line and gets the photo output:

```
list(price3)

['[',
 '[',
 "'",
 'S',
 '-',
 '1',
 "'",
 ',',
 ' ',
...
```

You must then transform the string `price3` in the corresponding list before writing the csv file. To do this you can use this trick:

```
import ast
price3_str = re.sub('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});', '', str(price2)) #remove special characters or html tags in original .txt files
price3 = ast.literal_eval(price3_str)
```

Now you can create the csv:

```
import csv
with open('pricerange3.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        wr = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=";")
        wr.writerow(["file_form", "filedate", "coname", "cik", "price_range"])  # Headlines in  top row
        wr.writerows(price3)
```

Answer (score 5):

No bugs, Excel by default uses the '`;`' instead of the '`,`', then in your example it inserts all the values ​​in the first column. To correctly view the  csv, you have to change the excel settings the separator character from '`;`' a '`,`' or save your csv file with the delimiter '`;`', as follows:

```
with open('pricerange.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        wr = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=";")
        wr.writerow(["file_form", "filedate", "coname", "cik", "price_range"])  # Headlines in  top row
        wr.writerows(price2)
```

Comment: Thank you @Massifox. Maybe I am not clear in the exposition. The first output ('price2' list) is perfect. The problem is that when I try to remove the html tags with the 'price3' list, then the output got messed up in the first column. I can't understand why it happens in price3 and it does not happen in price2...

Comment: I understand what you mean, now I'll give you a new answer, but I don't delete this because it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with `price3` because you converted `price2` to string to use `re.sub()` and later `writerows()` has problem to write it because it needs list of rows but it gets only single string. And it treads string as list of chars and put every char in separated row.

You should use list comprehension to run `re` with every element on list separatelly.

**EDIT:** As Massifox noticed in comment original version didn't work correctly but I added internal `for`-loop and now it works correctly.

```
price3 = [[re.sub('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});', '', item) for item in row] for row in price2]
```

Comment: It's wrong. This way you don't solve the problem. Because `writerows` takes an iterable of iterables of cells to write, and in this way you are still passing a string. Therefore, with this solution, instead of writing all the characters in the same column, n characters per line are written, with n length of the string representing the line.

Comment: @Massifox i didn't test it with `writerows` before so I missed it but now I added internal `for`-loop and it create correct `csv`

Comment: OK! I got it. Write it in your answer, otherwise the error I was telling you about in the previous comment occurs. Thanks :)

Comment: I changed code before my previous comment but now I added info that I changed code to fix problem which you found.